# npm does not install new package after modifying package.json

Tags: npm

I have a web application with some packages defined in package.json after I run npm install all dependencies are resolved. However when I add some packages after that to package.json and run npm install again nothing happens. I did the work around by typing npm install --save lodash and it downloaded the dependency and updated packages.json. It works, but let's imagine the scenario when I want to add 10 or more packages. Then it would be easier for me to just add them to package.json and run npm install but this does not work :/. So what would be the solution for the problem off adding more packages after initial npm install?

Node version: v8.1.3
npm version: 5.03
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.